# Average across some rows in R

Tags: r, average

I have not found a way to take an average across SOME columns in R when working with a data frame table. Basically, I want to take the average of the 3 controls (CTR_R1+CTR_R2+CTR_R3) and insert that value as another column right after CTR_R3 (see below). The same for the TRT. 
Is there away to take the average and insert it in a specific location?

```
GeneID|CTR_R1|CTR_R2|CTR_R3|CTR_AVG|TRT_R1| TRT_R2| TRT_R3|TRT_AVG|pValue
```

Comment: add reproducible code and show us what you tried or we can't/won't help you

Comment: `library(plyr); df <- mutate(df, CTR_AVG = (CTR_R1 + CTR_R2 + CTR_R3) / 3)`

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
df$CTR_AVG <- rowMeans(df[,2:4])
df$TRT_AVG <- rowMeans(df[,6:8])
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work even if there are many `CTR` or `TRT` columns (i.e. 100s).  But, I am guessing @beginneR's solution to be faster.

```
indx <- grep("^CTR", colnames(df1), value=TRUE)
indxT <- grep("^TRT", colnames(df1), value=TRUE)
df1[,c('CTR_Avg', 'TRT_Avg')] <- lapply(list(indx, indxT), 
                    function(x) Reduce(`+`, df1[,x])/length(x))
```

or you can use `rowMeans` in the above step.

```
df2 <- df1[,c('GeneID', indx, 'CTR_Avg', indxT, 'TRT_Avg', 'pValue')]

head(df2,2)
#    GeneID CTR_R1 CTR_R2 CTR_R3  CTR_Avg TRT_R1 TRT_R2 TRT_R3 TRT_Avg pValue
#1      1      6      2     10 6.000000     10     11     15      12  0.091
#2      2      5     12      8 8.333333      5      3     13       7  0.051
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20,20*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=6))
colnames(df1) <- c("CTR_R1", "CTR_R2", "CTR_R3", "TRT_R1", "TRT_R2", "TRT_R3")
df1 <- cbind(GeneID=1:20, df1, 
            pValue=sample(seq(0.001, 0.10, by=0.01), 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: other answers are way simpler

Comment: @phonixor Some answers also rely on the positions of the example data.  Also, suppose there are `100` Ctrl` and `100 `Trt` columns, I wouldn't do `df$CTR_R1+df$CTR_R2+...df$CRT_R100`

Comment: yeah they should have used colnames :), but your answer is the only one that adds the column at the desired spot...

Comment: if it where 100 columns, then i would use df[2:101] instead of colnames... might just aswell have different colnames were your reg expression would not work...

Comment: i would put data on top, so you can just run everything

Comment: @phonixor Yes, we can have several permutations/situations where the columns are not in order too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64025/discussion-between-phonixor-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you, if your data.frame is named `df`:

```
df$CTR_AVG <- ( df$CTR_R1 + df$CTR_R2 + df$CTR_R3 ) / 3
```

That is assuming that the `CTR_AVG` column already exists as you shown in your question. If it does not the code will put the column at the end of the data.frame.  To move it to the right spot, you will need to select the columns in the correct order, like so:

```
df[ , c( 'GeneID', 'CTR_R1', 'CTR_R2', 'CTR_R3', 'CTR_AVG', 'TRT_R1', 'TRT_R2', 'TRT_R3','TRT_AVG','pValue' ]
```

Comment: Well, it would work even if CTR_AVG would not exist.

Comment: @thothal, It would *not* work.  The OP's question asked for the column to be inserted after `CTR_R3`. The code I offered would insert  it as a new column at the end of `df`.

Comment: ok my bad. I meant that the line is working w/o an error. The column would not appear at the 'right' spot. I read your comment like 'it works w/o an error only if it is already existing'.

Comment: @thothal, I updated the response for more clarity.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

make some dummy data

```
df=data.frame(CTR_R1=1:10,CTR_R2=1:10,CTR_R3=1:10,somethingelse=1:10)
```

get a new column

```
df$CTR_AVG=apply(df[c("CTR_R1","CTR_R2","CTR_R3")],1,mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your replies. I am sorry I did not phrase my original question better. I meant to ask how to write one script to take the average and place that value in the right place. I do not have in my table the column that says "CTR_AVG", nor the column "TRT_AVG". 
I was wondering if i could do it more 'elegantly' than doing what i did below (which works too).

Many thanks.

#

names (edgeR_table)

"GeneID" "CTR_R1" "CTR_R2" "CTR_R3" "TRT_R1" "TRT_R2" "TRT_R3" "logFC" "logCPM" "LR" "PValue" "FDR"

#

edgeR_table$CTR_AVG <- rowMeans(edgeR_table[,2:4])

edgeR_table$TRT_AVG <- rowMeans(edgeR_table[,5:7])

edgeR_table <- edgeR_table[, c(1,2,3,4,13,5,6,7,14,8,9,10,11,12)]

Comment: You can use `grep` to identify the columns `CTR` and `TRT` when you have an unordered dataset.

Comment: Slightly shorter than your code would be: `edgeR_table[, c(1:4,13,5:7,14,8:12)]`